# How do I debug an Emscripten segmentation fault due to exceeding the available dynamic heap

Tags: c, emscripten

I am trying to compile an open source library using Emscripten and after making a few minor changes I have it compiling and running, but when I try to actually use it too much I am getting:

```
segmentation fault, exceeded the top of the available dynamic heap when loading 1 bytes from address 1869770797. STATICTOP=184544, DYNAMICTOP=21213184 melt.html:1246:11
exception thrown: abort("segmentation fault, exceeded the top of the available dynamic heap when loading 1 bytes from address 1869770797. STATICTOP=184544, DYNAMICTOP=21213184") at jsStackTrace@http://localhost:6931/melt.js:1603:13
stackTrace@http://localhost:6931/melt.js:1620:12
abort@http://localhost:6931/melt.js:52047:44
SAFE_HEAP_LOAD@http://localhost:6931/melt.js:926:51
_strcmp@http://localhost:6931/melt.wasm:wasm-function[912]:0x67c58
```

But I really don't think it should be using that much memory? What is the best way to debug memory issues like this with Emscripten in the browser?

I can't seem to even find the exact "strcmp" call it is failing on as the stack information kinda sucks.

If I compile without `-s SAFE_HEAP=1` the error comes through as:

```
exception thrown: RuntimeError: index out of bounds,_strcmp@http://localhost:6931/melt.wasm:wasm-function[771]:0x34dcf
Module._strcmp@http://localhost:6931/melt.js:50463:10
```

The library I am trying to compile is MLT framework (https://github.com/mltframework/mlt)

It's a bit complicated as well as it uses dynamic linking to load most of its features - right now I am just trying to get it working with the absolute minimum - mltframework itself (statically linked into the executable), libmltcore (loaded via dlload), libmltsdl2 (loaded via dlload)

Compile flags are as follows, for MLT itself (using WASM=0 but it doesn't seem to make a difference WASM or not):

```
emcc -g -s WASM=0 -dynamiclib -current_version 6.14.0 
-compatibility_version 6 
-o ../../../lib/libmlt.bc 
mlt_frame.o mlt_version.o mlt_geometry.o mlt_deque.o mlt_property.o mlt_properties.o mlt_events.o mlt_parser.o mlt_service.o mlt_producer.o mlt_multitrack.o mlt_playlist.o mlt_consumer.o mlt_filter.o mlt_transition.o mlt_field.o mlt_tractor.o mlt_factory.o mlt_repository.o mlt_pool.o mlt_tokeniser.o mlt_profile.o mlt_log.o mlt_cache.o mlt_animation.o mlt_slices.o  
-lpthread -lm
```

libmltcore:

```
emcc -g -s EXPORT_ALL=1 -s WASM=0 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -dynamiclib 
-o ../../../../lib/mlt/libmltcore.js 
factory.o producer_colour.o producer_consumer.o producer_hold.o producer_loader.o producer_melt.o producer_noise.o producer_timewarp.o producer_tone.o filter_audiochannels.o filter_audiomap.o filter_audioconvert.o filter_audiowave.o filter_brightness.o filter_channelcopy.o filter_crop.o filter_data_feed.o filter_data_show.o filter_fieldorder.o filter_gamma.o filter_greyscale.o filter_imageconvert.o filter_luma.o filter_mirror.o filter_mono.o filter_obscure.o filter_panner.o filter_region.o filter_rescale.o filter_resize.o filter_transition.o filter_watermark.o transition_composite.o transition_luma.o transition_mix.o transition_region.o transition_matte.o consumer_multi.o consumer_null.o 
-L../../framework -lmlt -lm -lpthread
```

litmltsdl2:

```
emcc -g -s EXPORT_ALL=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1 -s WASM=0 -dynamiclib 
-o ../../../../lib/mlt/libmltsdl2.js 
factory.o common.o consumer_sdl2.o consumer_sdl2_audio.o 
-L../../framework -lmlt -lpthread -lm -s USE_SDL=2
```

And finally my executable:

```
emcc -g -s SAFE_HEAP=1 -s WASM=0 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=1024MB -s EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1 -s MAIN_MODULE=1 
-O2 -I$(pwd)/dist/include/mlt $(pwd)/dist/lib/libmlt.bc 
--preload-file lib/mlt 
--preload-file lib/share 
melt.c -o melt.html --pre-js melt_pre.js
```

I've tried various other flags:

```
ALIASING_FUNCTION_POINTERS=0
SAFE_HEAP=1
STACK_OVERFLOW_CHECK=1
EMULATE_FUNCTION_POINTER_CASTS=1 
ASSERTIONS=2
```

-g4 seems like it might be helpful but tt fails to find the source files when building the libraries.

Comment: Could you tell us what library you are compiling, and what `emcc` compile options you use?

Comment: Added more info

Answer (score 1):

It worth taking a look [at the full list and descriptions of emcc compiler options](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js). You will realize all of other flags you mentioned won't help your case after reading the description from the link.

Firstly I'm pretty sure that you can't use `MB` notations for `-s TOTAL_MEMORY=` flag, since as you can see above, `-s` flags are actually JavaScript. Try using a plain integer instead. Also `-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1` will let the heap grow automatically as you need.

Note that pthread is not available in some browsers by default, since it (`SharedArrayBuffer` precisely) was affected by Meltdown vulnerability so it is disabled in the browsers.

Comment: Setting it to 1.5gb in bytes still didn't help (-s TOTAL_MEMORY=1610612736)